# More Multidimensional Array Issues

Tags: vba, loops, multidimensional-array

I am trying ti fill arrays based on conditions, and it seems my sample code is sticking values in the wrong position. I included the position where it is being altered. I tried doing some basic +1/-1 fixes but so far all these efforts have misplaced things or returned various other errors.

to be more clear- the issue is that  in the v loop, the value is being stuck in the (o,0) position instead of the (o,v) position (over writing the previous value).

I thought the way I had it structured would for each loop perform o's criteria and then check for v's criteria and in turn when v would loop would enter the value in the v position that is equal to the current value of o?

Im clearly missing something and any pointers in the correct direction would be gladly appreciated

```
Dim Cbox(9, 1)

For o = LBound(Cbox, 1) To UBound(Cbox, 1)
    If LPDif2 = 0 Then
        Cbox(o, 0) = 0
    ElseIf LPDif2 < 3 And LPDif2 > 0 Then
        CCount = CCount + LPDif2
        Cbox(o, 0) = LPDif2
    Else
        CCount = CCount + 3
        Cbox(o, 0) = 3
        LPDif2 = CNLP - CCount
    End If

    LPDif2 = CNLP - CCount
    If CCount = CNLP Then BCount = BCount + 1
    WCount = WCount + CW
    If CCount < CNLP And CCount >= Round(CLng(CNLP) / 2 + 0.000001, 0) Then DCount = DCount + 1
    If CCount >= CNLP Then DCount = DCount + 2

    For v = LBound(Cbox, 2) To UBound(Cbox, 2)
        If CCount >= Round(CLng(CNLP) / 2 + 0.000001, 0) And DCount = 1 Then
            Cbox(o, v) = "Green"
            If CTCombo = "9 W" Then
                AXWCount = WCount / 2
                WH.Value = Ceiling(AXWCount, 9)
            Else
                WH.Value = WCount
            End If
        End If
    Next v
Next o
```

Comment: please add more details about your issue

Comment: added more detail, sorry i thought it was clear

Comment: I'm guessing that the "random if" isn't so random.  All the *posted* code does is fill a 10 by 2 array with "Green". This would be easier to see what was happening if the entire loop was there.

Comment: fair enough give me a second :)

Comment: So, to clarify, all the conditions evaluate properly, its just that that the position in the array that "green" gets stored in is incorrect. I used various Debug.Print methods to pinpoint this, and to evaluate the proper calculations are being done, its just i have fubar'd the array part somehow :/

Comment: The top part of the outer loop is always writing to `(o, 0)`. Is the "Green" value only supposed to be in `(o, 1)`?

Comment: yessir. Though that does help me pinpoint my issue. I had strucutre it to say loop o_loopv  and then code but that wasnt working too well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, the code inside of the inner loop should only be running if the value of `v` is 1.  It should be as simple as just eliminating the inner loop entirely and hard coding the value "1":

```
For o = LBound(Cbox, 1) To UBound(Cbox, 1)
    '...
    If CCount >= Round(CLng(CNLP) / 2 + 0.000001, 0) And DCount = 1 Then
        Cbox(o, 1) = "Green"
        If CTCombo = "9 W" Then
            AXWCount = WCount / 2
            WH.Value = Ceiling(AXWCount, 9)
        Else
            WH.Value = WCount
        End If
    End If
Next o
```

Comment: AAAaaaaand of course the most simplistic answer is what turns out to be the case. Im a giant idiot O_o Thanks